# "cp -f" is failing because "file already exists"

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have a postinstall script that runs `cp -f ./foo/a.json ./node_modules/bar/a.json` and it is failing with an error that the file already exists (which it does, but I'm trying to overwrite it with my own version).

Isn't the whole point of the `-f` flag to make sure that it is a forced overwrite, even if the file exists?

I tried overriding any possible aliases for `cp` with `\cp`... same result. This is happening inside a docker build execution which is now running `npm install`, which then kicks off the npm postinstall script.

Here's example docker build output as requested:

```
#10 82.12 npm WARN lifecycle core-js@2.6.12~postinstall: cannot run in wd core-js@2.6.12 node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}" (wd=/node_modules/core-js)
#10 82.22 
#10 82.22 > xxx-cli@1.0.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/xxx-cli
#10 82.22 > command cp -f ./foo/a.json ./node_modules/xxx-library/assets/a.json
#10 82.22 
#10 82.31 cp: can't create './node_modules/xxx-library/assets/a.json': File exists
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How about `command cp -f`? What's the output of `which cp` and `file $(which cp)`?

Comment: command prefix didn't work. will try and add which cmds...

Comment: With a very heavy heart voting to close as unclear since yen doesn't show the actual, character-for-character error messages, and these would be crucial to solving this.

Answer (score 2):

no, that's not what `-f` is for. GNU coreutils' `cp` (which I presume is the `cp` you're using since you say you've got linux and run a bash) by *default* overwrites the *contents* of existing target files. (You need to explicitly disable that using `-n`.)

In the case a target file exists, but cannot be opened (for whatever reason), `-f` makes a difference and deletes the file, and makes a new one, and then fills that with the original's data. This seems to not solve nor be the problem at hand here.

You might want to be **very** verbatim about the wording of the error message.

Anyway, does `cat ./foo/a.json > ./node_modules/bar/a.json` work? It's effectively the same as your `cp ./foo/a.json ./node_modules/bar/a.json`, in that it simply overwrites the content of the target with the source.

Comment: cat did not work either. I'm beginning to think cp being ran by npm as a post-install hook inside of a docker build process is... maybe too many layers of indirection :(

Comment: "didn't work either": **verbatim** error messages, **edited** into your question, or we can't help you :(

Comment: verbatim with scrubbed pkg names added

Comment: Actually... after doing that, i think i figured out what was wrong... npm install had been invoked with `-g`, and so i don't think node_modules was even where I expected it to be. Removed that, and cmds worked just fine! So **you solved my issue by insisting on verbatim logs**... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Moved from question, since it's the answer:</sup>

This whole question turns out to be a nothing burger. The dockerfile in question was invoking npm install with the `-g` for globally installed modules, so I think I just couldn't overwrite the files in `node_modules` either bcos of permissions or because they weren't located where I thought they would be. Removing the `-g` and replacing it with `ci` caused everything to work as expected.